# Auto update timestamp column in oracle and sql server, without triggers

Tags: sql-server, oracle, timestamp

In MySQL, I can create a table with a timestamp column which value gets updated automatically when other columns change:

```
CREATE TABLE t (ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                  ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

What would be the best way to do something similar in SQL Server? And what about in Oracle? Can I do this without using triggers?

Comment: When you do write the triggers, make sure to account for multirow updates! This is critical in SQL server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For SQL Server, take a look at [rowversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx).

However, this will only give you an "arbitrary" versioning of your row, and will not provide an actual time stamp of your updates:

> The rowversion data type is just an incrementing number and does not preserve a date or a time.

As far as I know, a true time-stamp version in SQL Server is not possible without a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle, even up to version 11gR2, the DEFAULT clause on a column definition only applies to the value assigned when omitted on an INSERT. A trigger seems to be your only option in Oracle as well.